# JsonReader for generic type with List

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have the following domain model and JsonFormat/JsonReader definitions:

```
import spray.json._

case class User(name: String)

case class ValueResponse[T](value: T)
case class ValueListResponse[T](values: List[T])

object ApiProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  // some of my entities have JsonFormat but some only JsonReader
  implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat1[String, User](User)

  implicit def valueReader[T : JsonReader] = new JsonReader[ValueResponse[T]] {
    def read(value: JsValue): ValueResponse[T] = {
      value.asJsObject.fields.get("value") match {
        case Some(value: JsObject) => ValueResponse(value.convertTo[T])
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def valueListReader[T : JsonReader] = new JsonReader[ValueListResponse[T]] {
    def read(value: JsValue): ValueListResponse[T] = {
      value.asJsObject.fields.get("values") match {
        case Some(values: JsArray) => ValueListResponse(values.convertTo[List[T]])
                                                                        ^
[error] Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for List[T]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two implicit JsonReader definitions:

- `valueReader[T]` for `ValueResponse[T]` (for single value of type T)
- and `valueListReader[T]` for `ValueListResponse[T]` (for response with a list of values of type T)

Reader definitions are almost identical for both types.
The first definition works fine, but for the second compiler fails with error.

**Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for List[T]**

Interesting that if I replace parameter constraint `T: JsonReader` with `T: JsonFormat` it compiles fine.

But I would want to preserve the `T: JsonReader` constraint instead of `T: JsonFormat` because some of my entities (`T`) will will have only reader implementation.

I suspect I messed up with bounds of parameter definitions but I don't understand how.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `import DefaultJsonProtocol._` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect maybe spray only has an implicit definition for a `JsonFormat[List[T]]` given a `JsonFormat[T]`, not a `JsonReader[List[T]]` given a `JsonReader[T]`. Fortunately that's pretty simple to do yourself, something like:

```
implicit def listReader[T : JsonReader]: JsonReader[List[T]] = new JsonReader[List[T]] {
  def read(value: JsValue): List[T] = value match {
    case JsArray(elements) => elements.map(_.convertTo[T]).toList
    case x => deserializationError("Expected List as JsArray, but got " + x)
  }
}
```

It actually makes me wonder why they didn't just define all of their implicit `JsonReader`s and `JsonWriter`s separately and then have a single `implicit def bothToFormat[T : JsonReader : JsonWriter]: JsonFormat[T]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the case.

Comment: Awesome! I though I was going to have a bad time fixing this issue in an old library. This solved perfectly, thanks!